# Beginner's guide to $A_{\infty}$-algebras

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, operads, higher-algebra, a-infinity-algebras

I have some general questions about $A_{\infty}$-algebras. Altough I
understand bare definition from  [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/A-infinity-algebra) I have no association how to think
intuitively about them. Which picture one should
have in mind thinking of $A_{\infty}$-algebras? What makes them interesting in higher algebra & theory of spectra? Which questions from these areas they primary help to attack?  Hope, it's not to broad formulated.

How they are concretly related to a infinity loop spaces? Can they be thought as a natural homotopy theoretical pendant of infinity loop spaces? (i.e. that $A_{\infty}$-algebras are related to infinity loop spaces like homotopical colimits to usual limits? Or is this a bad intuition?)

In this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365447/loop-spaces-motivation) Naruki Masuda wrote an interesting comment I would like
to understand:

> By considering loops parametrized by [0, t] for all t\geq 0, you
> see that a loop space is a deformation retract of a
> (strictly unital and associative) topological monoid.
> But a strict algebra structure is not preserved by homotopy
> equivalence, so topological monoids are not a correct notion
> of 'homotopical associative monoid.'
> The definition of A-infinity algebra, which is the homotopically
> correct intrinsic notion of associative monoids, takes a cue
> from the recognition of algebraic structures present in loop spaces.

I would like to elaborate precisely how the
definition of A-infinity algebra arise precisely from
recognition of algebraic structures present in loop spaces.
Can this a bit "hand weavy observation" be made more precise?

Additionally, I heared that $A_{\infty}$-algebras become quite
important in physics (TQFT). I'm
looking for a sketchy
motivation how these structures in theoretical physics naturally occure.

Comment: IMHO your question is too broad, but shortly, a space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a loop space iff it is an A-infinity algebra and the monoid $\pi_0X$ is a group. A-infinity algebras show up in many ways in maths. The relation with infinity loop spaces, you got it wrong, you need E-infinity for that. For a quick introduction: Keller, Bernhard. 2001. “Introduction to A∞-Infinity Algebras and Modules.” Homology, Homotopy and Applications 3 (1): 1–35. https://doi.org/10.4310/HHA.2001.v3.n1.a1. Beware however that all such introductions are biased by the author's scientific interests.

Comment: I'm a fan of Vallette's [Algebra+Homotopy=Operad](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3245).

Comment: Consider taking a look at [Proute's thesis](http://163.172.10.123:8080/these_A_Proute-TAC.pdf) and [Lefevre-Hasegawa's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310337).